# How to use mongodb skip() and limit() in meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

How to use `skip()` and `limit()` in meteor?

```
Post.find({"user_id":user_id}).skip(0).limit(5);
```

when I execute above line server says

> Exception while invoking method 'Userpost' TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'skip'

Answer (score 53):

You should try putting the skip and limit options as an object parameter within the **[`find()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-find)** method as follows:

```
Post.find({"user_id":user_id}, {skip: 0, limit: 5});
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is the doc about [collection.find([selector], [options])](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-find)

skip and limit are options of the find method